# __unused Flag Behavior/Usage (GCC with Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gcc

I just now learned about the __unused flag that can be used when compiling with GCC and the more I learn about it, the more questions I have...

Why does this compile without warning/error?  It seems strange that I specifically tell the compiler I won't be using a variable, then when I use it, things proceed as normal.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self foo:0];
}

- (void)foo:(NSInteger)__unused myInt
{
    myInt++;
    NSLog(@"myInt: %d", myInt);  // Logs '1'
}
```

Also, what is the difference between the following two method signatures?

```
- (void)foo:(NSInteger)__unused myInt;

- (void)foo:(NSInteger)myInt __unused;
```

Comment: They are equivalent and you can also write `- (void)foo:(__unused NSInteger)myInt;` and `- (void)foo:(NSInteger __unused)myInt;`.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The `__unused` macro (which is in fact expanded to the `__attribute__((unused))` GCC attribute) only tells the compiler "don't warn me if I don't use this variable".

> `unused`: This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC does not produce a warning for this variable. *([Source: gnu.gcc.org doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes))*

So this GCC attribute is to **avoid a warning** when you don't use a variable, and **NOT to trigger one** when you use the variable you claimed unused.

---

As regard to putting the attribute before or after the variable name in your last example, both are accepted and equivalent in your case: the compiler is just lenient about that placement for compatibility purposes (quite as you can also write both `const int i` or `int const i`)

> For compatibility with existing code written for compiler versions that did not implement attributes on nested declarators, some laxity is allowed in the placing of attributes *([Source: gnu.gcc.org doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax))*

Comment: Is the RHS safe not to be optimized away by the compiler?

Answer (score 12):

As of Xcode 7.3.1, there is currently no difference between:

```
- (void)foo:(NSInteger)__unused myInt;// [syntax 1]
- (void)foo:(NSInteger __unused)myInt;// [syntax 2]
- (void)foo:(__unused NSInteger)myInt;// [syntax 3]
```

But the following doesn't work:

```
- (void)foo:(NSInteger)myInt __unused;// [doesn't work]
```

For usage on this, [Apple recommends first syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_6). ([information was partially taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/285750/1033581))

But there is difference between:

```
__unused NSString *foo, *bar;  // [case a] attribute applies to foo and bar
NSString *foo __unused, *bar;  // [case b] attribute applies to foo only

NSString * __unused foo, *bar; // [case c] attribute applies to foo only
NSString __unused *foo, *bar;  // [case d] attribute applies to foo and bar
CFStringRef __unused foo, bar; // [case e] attribute applies to foo and bar
```

If we want `__unused` to apply to all, syntax [a] is my personal best as it leaves no ambiguity.

If we want `__unused` to apply to one, syntax [b] is my personal best as it leaves no ambiguity.

The latter three solutions are acceptable but confusing in my opinion. ([information was partially taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21154112/1033581))

---

And while we're talking about the order of keywords, kind reminder:

```
const NSString *foo = bar;  // BAD: foo is NOT const
NSString const *foo = bar;  // BAD: foo is NOT const
NSString *const foo = bar;  // GOOD: foo is const
```