# Are "NSString * __unused aString" and "NSString __unused * aString" equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, clang

1. Are `NSString * __unused aString` and `NSString __unused * aString` equivalent, when they are variable declarations?
2. Are `- (void)aMethod:(NSString * __unused)aString` and `- (void)aMethod:(NSString __unused *)aString` equivalent, when they are Objective-C method parameter declarations?
3. If the answer is "yes", what form should I prefer as correct?

Both forms in both cases seem to work identically when enabling/disabling `GCC_WARN_UNUSED_PARAMETER` and `GCC_WARN_UNUSED_VARIABLE` directives.

I didn't find any information to clarify this.

---

Relevant topics:

[__unused Flag Behavior/Usage (GCC with Objective C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736107/unused-flag-behavior-usage-gcc-with-objective-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between the two.

When the attribute, `__unused`, appears before the star, it decorates the primary type of the entire declaration list.  All variables will be "unused":

`__unused NSString *foo, *bar;  // OK.  All variables are unused in the statement.
NSString __unused *foo, *bar;   // OK`

But when placed after the `*`, it will only apply to the first variable:

`NSString * __unused foo, *bar; // Unused variable 'bar'`

I prefer `NSString * __unused foo;` because it seems more clear to me and won't hide the rare case when I declare multiple variables in one statement.

The [GCC Attribute Syntax](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html#Attribute-Syntax) reference mentions it in Section 6.31:

> An attribute specifier list may appear immediately before a declarator
>   (other than the first) in a comma-separated list of declarators in a
>   declaration of more than one identifier using a single list of
>   specifiers and qualifiers. Such attribute specifiers apply only to the
>   identifier before whose declarator they appear. For example, in
>
> ```
>  __attribute__((noreturn)) void d0 (void),
>      __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) d1 (const char *, ...),
>       d2 (void)
> ```
>
> the noreturn attribute applies to all the functions declared; the format attribute only applies to d1.

Answer (score 1):

There's a third option which behaves similarly: `__unused NSString *`. This seems more common on [Github](https://github.com/search?l=objective-c&q=%22__unused%22&ref=searchresults&type=Code) at least.

For method declarations there is another style similar to the second option in your list:

```
- (void)aMethod:(NSString *) __unused aString
```

I read from right-to-left. Going through your list, I read `NSString * __unused` as an "unused pointer to an NSString instance" and I read `NSString __unused *` as a "pointer to an unused NSString instance". The former, i.e. #1 in your list, makes the most sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please, see [this](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/624) about not having __unused inside parenthesises. This is the reason why I excluded it from the list of options in my question.