# Updating Objective-C syntax with Swift equivalent for unused static

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am stuck on translating a method from the following bit.

In original Objective-C, the method is:

```
+ (CGFloat)defaultFontSize
{
    CGFloat pointSize = 16.0;
    NSString *contentSizeCategory = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] preferredContentSizeCategory];
    pointSize += SLKPointSizeDifferenceForCategory(contentSizeCategory); //stucj here

    return pointSize;
}
```

In Swift, I have done the following so far:

```
let defaultFontSize: Float {
        get {
            let pointSize = 16.0
            let contentSizeCategory = UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory
            //What do here for SLKPointSizeDifferenceForCategory?
     }
}
```

In particular, I don't know how to translate `SLKPointSizeDifferenceForCategory`, which is an `unused static CGFloat`:

```
__unused static CGFloat SLKPointSizeDifferenceForCategory(NSString *category)
{
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraSmall])                         return -3.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategorySmall])                              return -2.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryMedium])                             return -1.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryLarge])                              return 0.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraLarge])                         return 2.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraLarge])                    return 4.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryExtraExtraExtraLarge])               return 6.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityMedium])                return 8.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityLarge])                 return 10.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraLarge])            return 11.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraLarge])       return 12.0;
    if ([category isEqualToString:UIContentSizeCategoryAccessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge])  return 13.0;
    return 0;
}
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just a function that returns a `CGFloat`:

```
func SLKPointSizeDifference(for category: UIContentSizeCategory) -> CGFloat {
    typealias c = UIContentSizeCategory // for the sake of reducing boilerplate below

    switch category {
    case c.extraSmall:                         return -3
    case c.small:                              return -2
    case c.medium:                             return -1
    case c.large:                              return 0
    case c.extraLarge:                         return 2
    case c.extraExtraLarge:                    return 4
    case c.extraExtraExtraLarge:               return 6
    case c.accessibilityMedium:                return 8
    case c.accessibilityLarge:                 return 10
    case c.accessibilityExtraLarge:            return 11
    case c.accessibilityExtraExtraLarge:       return 12
    case c.accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge:  return 13
    default:                                   return 0
    }
}
```

- `__unused` is just a flag that tells the compiler not to warn if that function is never used. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736107/unused-flag-behavior-usage-gcc-with-objective-c).
- `static` just limits the scope of that function's existence to the current file.
- `UIContentSizeCategory` is imported into Swift as a struct, which is more strongly typed than just using raw strings.

Answer (score 1):

[`__unused`  only tells the compiler "don't warn me if I don't use this variable".](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736383/981049), and in this context I believe that means no warning should be shown if the result of `SLKPointSizeDifferenceForCategory` goes unused.

[As for the Slack SDK function you're trying to port](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/blob/master/Source/SLKUIConstants.h), why not simply include SlackTextViewController in your bridging header and then you can pick up the original function like magic.

Comment: Nope, the [corresponding page for function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) says: "the function is meant to be possibly unused". There is by default no warning for unused function results; the `warn_unused_result` attribute enables it.

Comment: There are certainly warnings for unused function results [(by default) in Swift](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-3-warning-of-unused-result/) @jtbandes