# Store function in array

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function called update that looks like this:

```
func update(animated: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

}
```

Now I want to queue multiple calls to this function in an array. How can I do this?

I need an array with a type:

```
var queue = [???]()
```

and to append the function like `queue.append(???)`, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify how you could achieve it, just copy your function signature:

```
(animated: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ())
```

and use it for declaring a *typealias*:

```
typealias Update = (animated: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ())
```

You'll see syntax error as:

> @escaping attribute may only be used in function parameter position

with a suggestion with removing the `@escaping`, do it:

```
typealias Update = (animated: Bool, completion: (Bool) -> ())
```

At this point, you will be able to recognize the appropriate type by using the `Update` typealias.

Therefore, you are able to declare your `queue` array as:

```
var queue = [Update]()
```

Note that when declaring a typealias you could just avoid naming the parameters, as:

```
// this is sufficient
typealias Update = (Bool, (Bool) -> ())
```

---

**Furthermore**:

For knowing what typealias is, you could check: [When to use typealias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47423793/when-to-use-typealias) (as well as the [story](https://medium.com/@ahmadfayyas/swift-quick-elegant-code-typealias-8e6d59f07f32) mentioned in its answer)

Comment: when declaring a type, or typealiasing a type isn't it always suggested to use UpperCamelCase?

Comment: @Scriptable true, I just forgot about this one, answer edited. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Literally just solved my own question after posting this. The answer is this:

```
private var queue = [(Bool, (Bool) -> ()) -> ()]()
```

and `queue.append(update)`