# Where is the __unused macro defined?

Tags: c

I saw once a usage of the macro `__unused` which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736107/unused-flag-behavior-usage-gcc-with-objective-c), but for some reason I can't find now where it is defined. Will appreciate help. I need it for an ansi C project. Thanks.

Comment: It's not an ANSI C macro however.

Comment: Also, you might wanna forget about "ANSI C" and instead use ISO C. The C language has been internationally standardized since the year 1990.

Comment: @Lundin good to know. I thought it just a term for "not c++".

Comment: "C" in and of itself implies "not C++".

Comment: @StoryTeller Can I define the macro myself?

Comment: @EladWeiss - I wouldn't define *that* macro (the two underscore spiel is reserved). But nothing is stopping you from defining your own macro that expands to `__attribute__((unused))`.

Comment: @EladWeiss: you can, but you should not. `__` is a reserved prefix. By definining something in it, you should break things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unused
```

is GCC specific [6.32.1 Common Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)

This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. `GCC` does not produce a warning for this variable.

[NTERNATIONAL STANDARD ©ISO/IEC ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does not even mention `unused`.